# TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN installed together - SVN+SSH settings messed up

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, ssh-keys, tortoisegit

I've been working with SVN (TortoiseSVN) through SSH for quite a while without any problem. Recently I had to add git, so I installed TortoiseGit.

Since then, my SSH connection for SVN suddenly doesn't work any longer. The error 'svn: Can’t create tunnel: The system cannot find the path specified' pointed me eventually to my environment variables, and I noticed that the SVN_SSH variable was changed to the plink included in TortoiseGit.

I have a separate Putty/Keygen/Pageant install that I used before, so I changed that environment variable back to the plink of Putty. Still, my system isn't using the SSH protocol any longer. I can update with TortoiseSVN, but I have to retype my password multiple times for every action I do. RStudio is not reacting (that one requires SSH to be used as it doesn't show the pop-up for the password)

- System: Windows 8.1 (fully updated)
- The used server: R-Forge.R-project.org
- The IDE : RStudio
- The used SVN : TortoiseSVN
- The current plink used by TortoiseSVN: tortoisePlink (option is not set in SVN)
  I also tried the Putty plink (that Pageant has the SSH keys), but to no avail.
- Environment Variable SVN_SSH: C:/Program Files (x86)/PuTTY/plink.exe
  (When it was C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\tortoiseplink, I got the error above)

I've been going through the settings but I can't seem to find the problem. Does anybody have an idea which setting or other issue I might be overlooking? I'd like to avoid to do a complete reinstall of my workflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit. Be aware that when installing TortoiseGit, the installation procedure adds some environment variables (GIT_SSH and SVN_SSH being the important ones) but uses backslashes for the paths. SVN_SSH probably looks like:

C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe

You should edit that one:

- if backslashes are used, change to forward slashes
- if any folder name contains a space, add quotation marks (that turned out to be my problem)

The end result for the environment variable SVN_SSH should then be:

"C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoisePlink.exe"

Restart your computer to update the values everywhere, and it should work again.